# Can't compile with extern library

Tags: c++, clang++

I've installed the jsoncpp library via vcpkg into my project directory. Since the compiler looks for header files mostly in predefined include directories how can I add the library to those directories so that the compiler can recognize it?

Error:
`fatal error: 'json.h' file not found`

Comment: Are you using Clang with VS, or with MinGW?

Comment: You need to add the extra include directories to your project, so they are given to the compiler when your source files are compiled.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am not using it with any of them. I am compiling the files in the terminal with clang++ -o ... .cpp

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I am using the official Clang build. Since I have a Mac I will not be able to use MinGW or similar.

Comment: Oh. Then disregard what I said about MinGW & VS.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I found the issue: The package wasn't installed properly due to a homebrew error. I had a shallowed version of homebrew. I had to unshallow and upgrade it and then download the package again, now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: The package wasn't installed properly due to a homebrew error. I had a shallowed version of homebrew. I had to unshallow and upgrade it and then download the package again, now it works.